# Facial Recognition in Flutter using Google ML Kit

Tags: flutter, deep-learning, face-detection, google-mlkit

I am doing a project that requires real time facial recognition for android and ios using flutter. After some research I found [Google's ML Kit library](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection). So essentially detecting a face from a phone camera and attaching a name to it from a predefined dataset.

Since we will be using flutter I found this repo made by Google's ML Kit team for example apps https://github.com/flutter-ml/google_ml_kit_flutter/tree/master. Again theres face detection and face mesh detection, I'm slightly confused where to start with and the best way to go about this.

The link I attached contains face detection (example 1 ) and and face contour detection (example 2). Which of those paths should I take to achieve my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ML Kit allows you to find faces in a picture/stream but it is not a face-recognition API

Comment: If it allows me to find faces in pictures and stream, shouldnt that be enough for my needs

Comment: That's not enough to recognise *who* the faces are though, I think that's what you want.

Comment: Yeah it is, what do you recommend instead, I'd like to find the faces, store that and then for it to recognise again those faces.

Comment: You could do something like that. First thing that comes to my mind is taking the stream of the video as pictures, make a CNN that runs through them and then check the new pictures against that CNN's output (1 for similar/0 for different). Please accept the answer as this I believe is what you needed as help. Best.

Comment: Is there perhaps another library I could use, there must be some library or framework that abstracts this type of stuff

Comment: Check maybe Regula Forensics? It is paid and has a steep price but that's what I worked with back in the day and it worked well.